When a sentence ends with italicized word, should the word be followed by italicized period or a regular period?
I always wondered wether you should style the period in italics if it follows the italicized word. Does anyone know what style guides say about this matter?
Which of the two following options is correct?
This is an *example*.
This is an *example.*

Thank you.

Looking at bold instead of italic, we can see that a final bolded word wants the calm of a vanilla period. That punctuation anchors the full sentence, not just the boulder.

How can you tell?

@KateBunting, LoL. I can't. But aren't there rules for everything.

Which style guides? If you're asking for a summary of different approaches, that would be off-topic on this site. And yes, there are rules for how our site operates.

This is between you and your style guide.
The Chicago Manual of Style would have your period in roman (not italic) type:

6.2: Punctuation and italics All punctuation marks should appear in the same font style—roman or italic—as the main or
surrounding text, except for punctuation that belongs to a title in a
different style (usually italics). For example, the word and, which
in this sentence is in italics, is followed by a comma in roman type
(also known as regular text) . . . Source: The Chicago Manual of
Style—6.2: Punctuation and
italics
(login required)


What do they mean by the main or surrounding text? Would be helpful to see how the two compare, especially in the context of this particular topic.

(login required):)

This is between you and your style guide. Well, my style guide is Chicago, although I can't log in :)

The Chicago Manual of Style's recommendation seems really misguided to me — there are cases where it makes no sense! If you have a whole phrase in italics, and the punctuation goes with the phrase, then it seems clear that you should italicize the punctuation.

@PeterShor Actually, although the kerning would look funny, I would be inclined to render your "!" in roman. BUT if you followed with another m-dash and more of the sentence: "... to me — there are cases where it makes no sense! — internal punctuation ought to match its phrase..." ...then I'd italicize it. But also I wouldn't be writing that sentence in anything academic...

Examples from CMOS:
For light amusement he turns to the Principia Mathematica!
but
Hello, Dolly! premiered on Broadway in 1964.

Traditionally, the period would be italicized, even if only the last word in the sentence were italicized.

While it doesn't really matter with periods, it makes sense with other punctuation marks. Consider the difference between Sold! and Sold! Which one looks better?

That's what I thought. It only makes sense: italics probably inherit from the quotation marks rules.

"Traditionally"? This answer could be improved by offering some evidence.
